# R putting list inside data frame

Tags: r, list, dataframe

I'm stuck trying to figure out how to get a list or vector into a data frame. Here's a minimal example.

```
#list or matrix "a"
a=rbind(c(1,2,3),c(4,5,6),c(7,8,9))
#data frame "b"
b=data.frame(veg=c("potato","pumpkin","carrot"))
```

Now I want to put row 1 of `a` into a new column and observation 1 of `b` e.g. `b$counts`. Then row 2 of `a` goes into observation 2 of `b$counts`. Does that make sense? I have searched all that I could think of to get this, but am at a loss for how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

We can have a `list` column by splitting by row

```
b$counts <- asplit(a, 1)
b
#        b  counts
#1  potato 1, 2, 3
#2 pumpkin 4, 5, 6
#3  carrot 7, 8, 9
```

Or use `split` by `seq_len(nrow(a))`

```
b$count <- split(a, seq_len(nrow(a)))
```